# Get max value from datetimes (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list

I have code to get all of values from table column and calculate average salary and max difference between salary dates.

Here is model for Salary

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Employee_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
```

And here is Viewmodel code

```
public class SalariesViewModel
{
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public decimal AverageSalary { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DateTime> Dates{ get; set; }
    public double MaxDifference { get; set; }
}
```

Here is code where I calculate average salary

```
     var maxdiff = 0;
        List<SalariesViewModel> result = new List<SalariesViewModel>();
        var employees = db.Employees.Select(x => new
        {
            Department = x.Department.Name,
            Name = x.Name,
            Salary = x.Salaries.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault().Amount,
            Date = x.Salaries.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault().Date 

        });



        var data = employees.GroupBy(m => m.Department).Select(x => new SalariesViewModel
        {
            DepartmentName = x.Key,
            AverageSalary = x.Average(y => y.Salary),
            Dates = x.Select(y=> y.Date).ToList()

        }).ToList();



        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count - 1; i++) {


        }

        return data;
    }
```

Also I need to calculate max difference

I can select only dates and calculate differences between them and find max. And then push to ViewModel.

But I think, it not good experience.

How I can do this in `data` query or in ViewModel?

**Update**

This might give some clues to anyway heading down this rabbit hole

*In response to Michael Randalls Answer*

> Yes. But you calculate difference beetween max and min values of date.
>   I need to calculate other. For example employee has 3 salary pays. I
>   need to show max time between those pays. So it would be 3 payment -2
>   payment , and 2 payment - 1 payment. and if for example 1 variant
>   difference is bigger, I need to show it.

Comment: Difference between what?

Comment: Sorry, updated post@MichaelRandall

Comment: You need only the max value?

Comment: Could you, please, provide some *examples*? Let initial list contains `1 Jan 2018`, `10 Jan 2018`, `21 Jan 2018`, `4 Jan 2018`; what is the desired outcome?

Comment: @Balance: still it is un-clear what you are asking, please tell us what you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, only max value @Sonali

Comment: `var result = differences.Max();`?

Comment: This still doesn't make sense `But I need to add max difference to List.` list of what. My brain is starting to hurt

Comment: What does `Employee.Date` represent? Birthdate? HireDate? And is it intentional that you don't order `Salaries` before choosing the `Date` (as you do with `Salary`)?

Comment: I will Update whole post now @RufusL

Comment: I will Update whole post now @MichaelRandall

Comment: You are looking for the max difference between elements that are next to each other in the list of dates, right? Assuming that the employees are in the hiring order, that would represent the largest gap, in seconds, between hiring two consecutive employees.

Comment: I updated my post@RufusL

Comment: I updated my post@MichaelRandall

Comment: I updated my post@dasblinkenlight

Comment: So this has nothing to do with date?

Comment: Why it nothing to do with date? I need to calculate difference between dates. I wrote at post.@MichaelRandall

Answer (score 2):

If you need to find only the max difference between adjacent elements, without making the entire list of `differences`, you can `Zip` the list with itself after skipping the initial element, and get `Max` this way:

```
var maxDiff = dates.Zip(dates.Skip(1), (c, n) => (n-c).TotalSeconds).Max();
```

Comment: "between adjacent elements" needs highlighting, I think.

Comment: @Balance Then you do need the max between adjacent dates without making an explicit list of `differences`, right?

Comment: I think yes, becuse it would be big code.@dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxdiff = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count - 1; i++)
{
  var result = (dates[i + 1] - dates[i]).TotalSeconds;
  if (maxdiff < result)
  {
        maxdiff = result;
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I am a gambling man, am i close?

```
var data = employees.GroupBy(m => m.Department).Select(x => new SalariesViewModel
{
    DepartmentName = x.Key,
    AverageSalary = x.Average(y => y.Salary),
    MaxDifference = (x.Max(y => y.Date) - x.Min(y => y.Date)).TotalDays,
 }).ToList()
```

Comment: Yes. But you calculate difference beetween max and min values of date. I need to calculate other. For example employee has 3 salary pays. I need to show max time between those pays. So it would be 3 payment -2 payment , and 2 payment - 1 payment. and if for example 1 variant difference is bigger, I nedd to show it.

Comment: I updated code. Now my question is how to do calculation in for loop